# Validations pass but when merge() is called a validation error is thrown

Tags: java, jpa, bean-validation, wildfly-10, vraptor

Sorry for asking here but I can't for the life of me understand what is going on. Been looking for answers all around the web for hours with no luck.

I have a simple Quiz modelled in JPA, using [VRaptor](http://www.vraptor.org/) (an MVC framework) running in a WildFly 10.0.0.Final server which uses Hibernate 5.0.7.Final. A Quiz have many Questions which have **2-10** Alternatives each.

I'm currently implementing a method for users to add/remove Questions on a Quiz. Before calling `merge(quiz)` I run the validations to make sure everything is valid. It passes. I get no errors.

Since there are no validation errors, I call `merge(quiz)` and finally I'm greeted with the following exception:

```
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [game.Question] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='Cannot be empty', propertyPath=alternatives, rootBeanClass=class game.Question, messageTemplate='{org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty.message}'}
]
```

[Edit] If I deliberately leave something blank it does show the validation error and doesn't try to `merge()`, so validations are being run as expected.

I've checked the whole thing manually and there really are no errors. Used this "alternative" method to check and print validation errors:

```
private void val(final Object obj, final String s) {
    final ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    final javax.validation.Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
    final Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(obj);
    for (final ConstraintViolation cv : constraintViolations) {
        log.info("-------------");
        log.info(s + " ValidatationConstraint: " + cv.getConstraintDescriptor().getAnnotation());
        log.info(s + " ValidatationConstraint: " + cv.getConstraintDescriptor());
        log.info(s + " ValidatationConstraint: " + cv.getMessageTemplate());
        log.info(s + " ValidatationConstraint: " + cv.getInvalidValue());
        log.info(s + " ValidatationConstraint: " + cv.getLeafBean());
        log.info(s + " ValidatationConstraint: " + cv.getRootBeanClass());
        log.info(s + " ValidatationConstraint: " + cv.getPropertyPath().toString());
        log.info(s + " ValidatationConstraint: " + cv.getMessage());
        log.info("-------------");
    }
}
```

This is roughly what my add/remove Questions method do:

```
@Transactional
public void updateQuestions(final String quizId, final List<Question> questions) {
    // Quizzes might have slugs (/quiz-name)
    final Quiz quiz = findQuizByIdString(quizId);
    if (quiz != null) {
        for (final Question question : questions) {
            question.setQuiz(quiz);

            if (question.getAlternatives() != null) {
                for (final Alternative alt : question.getAlternatives()) {
                    alt.setQuestion(question);
                }
            }

            if (question.getId() != null) {
                final Question old = (Question) ps.createQuery("FROM Question WHERE id = :id AND quiz = :quiz").setParameter("id", question.getId()).setParameter("quiz", quiz).getSingleResult();

                // Making sure the Question do belong to the this Quiz
                if (old == null) {
                    question.setId(null);
                }
            }

            if (question.getId() == null) {
                // Set the new question up (who created, timestamp, etc.)
            }
        }

        quiz.setQuestions(questions);

        if (!validator.validate(quiz).hasErrors()) {
            try {
                entityManager.merge(quiz);
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                if (log.isErrorEnabled()) { log.error("Error while updating Quiz Questions", e); }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        // Send an error to the user
    }
}
```

And finally these are the (what I think) relevant parts of my entities:

```
@Entity
public class Quiz {
    /* ... */
    @Valid // FYI: This just makes the validation cascade
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "quiz", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Question> questions;
    /* ... */
}

@Entity
public class Question {
    /* ... */
    @Valid
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 2, max = 10)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "question", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Alternative> alternatives;
    /* ... */
}

@Entity
public class Alternative {
    /* ... */
    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 0xFF)
    @Column(length = 0xFF, nullable = false)
    private String text; // The only field that must be filled
    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Got it. A friend suggested using `persist()` on the new Questions prior to the `merge()`.

Although he said its because `merge()` won't create the new entities it will. According to the JPA spec if the entity doesn't exist a new instance of it will be created in the persistence context and the original will be **copied** into it.

Copies, in Java, are the bane of all life. Since all instances of Question have an array (instance of `List`) of Alternatives *that* wasn't copied (as far as I know probably because `List` isn't an entity or simply because the copies are shallow).

Well, thanks anyway to anyone who tried to help and very good luck to anyone that might bump into this on the future.

[Edit]
Problem was because of the copying JPA does. Since `Quiz` have a `List<Question>` it'll be copied but for a reason I'm not quite totally sure *(shallow copies?)* the `List<Alternative>` of each `Question` wasn't being copied. That's why the `@NotEmpty` validation failed at the `alternatives` field of `Question`.

Calling `persist()` on each new `Question` before merging makes them part of the Persistence Context and a copy won't be necessary anymore.

Did it by doing this:

```
for (int i = 0, max = questions.size(); i < max; i++) {
    Question question = questions.get(i);

    /* all of that previous code */

    if (question.getId() == null) {
        entityManager.persist(question);
    }
    else {
        /* merge() returns the newly merged and managed (as in it is now part of
           the persistence context) instance, so replace the "old" one */
        questions.set(i, entityManager.merge(question));
    }
}
```